# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement protos ERROR: No matching distribution found for protos when trying to install protos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, protocol-buffers

I am trying to install protos using `pip install protos` but I get following error messages `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement protos  ERROR: No matching distribution found for protos` (these are 2 different lines btw). Does anybody have the same problem because maybe I do not meet the requirements but I the problem is that I don't know which requirements, I just don't find any information. I am using python 3.6.2, pip 20.3.3 and windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The `protos` package can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/protos/

According to the PyPi page, it requires Python 3.7 or greater. Since you are running Python 3.6 you get the error message when running `pip install protos`.

If you are looking for Google's protocol buffer, then you should look at `pip install protobuf` (docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/)).